# cakephp, how to link with two span

Tags: cakephp

How to add two span tags to a link?

```
<?php echo $this->Html->tag('span’, 
    $this->Html->link($v['name']['lastname'], 
    $v['link’]
    ); 
?>
```

```
//Output
<a class=« test" href="./#">
   <span>name</span>
   <span>lastname</span>
</a>
```

I'm not sure to be a good start, thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply concatenate two span tags with the HtmlHelper in the first argument of the link() method.

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('span', $v['name']) .
    $this->Html->tag('span', $v['lastname']),
    $v['link'],
    array('escape' => false)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should do it:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('<span>name</span><span>lastname</span>', '#', array('escape' => false)); ?>
```